# How do i listen for what url is typed in express/react?

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm new to React/Express apps and i have some trouble when i want to include more then one page in my project; 
How do i listen for what url is typed and render the appropriate page?
i.e I want to type localhost:3000/login, i want to render login. This works if i change the createElement(Commentary) to createElement(Login).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Commentary from './Commentary';
import Login from './Login';


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Commentary),
     document.getElementById('container')
  );
});
```

Comment: This is not a good approach at all. You should only ever have one container in which you render *ALL* of your react code. The actual output can then change depending on the URL if you use some kind of front-end routing library. [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) is by far the most common one.

Comment: Like here https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-react-apps-the-complete-guide ?

Comment: Looks like a good place to start.